# copyIntoItems() not assigning Title to the document in document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to assign a Title to already existing document in the document library using `copyIntoItems()`.
I am giving input as: `Title,ID,FileName`

The method is giving the following error:

```
Value does not fall within expected range
```

But if I provide `SourceFullPath,Title,ID,FileName` as the input, then it works fine.  I don't want to provide `<SourceFullPath>D:\test.txt</SourceFullPath>` here.

Can someone suggest how I can use `copyIntoItems` without providing the `SourceFullPath`?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. CopyIntoItems() is used to copy documents from one location to another (even between servers). Could you perhaps show some lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

To assign the field information you must set at least DisplayName, Type and value to Fields parameter from CopyIntoItems method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.fieldinformation_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
fieldInfo = new Sharepoint.FieldInformation();
fieldInfo.Id = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId.Title;
fieldInfo.Value = "New title";
fieldInfo.DisplayName = "Title";
fieldInfo.Type = YetAnotherMigrationTool.Library.SP2007.Sharepoint.FieldType.Text;
fieldInfo.InternalName = "Title";
fields.Add(fieldInfo);
```

For a full example how to upload a document to SharePoint using CopyIntoItems method see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy.copyintoitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Note: The absolute source URL of the document to be copied is a mandatory parameter.